# How to change the background color of a button in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In xaml I have :

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key = "TriggerStyle" TargetType = "Button">
            <Setter Property = "Foreground" Value = "Blue" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property = "IsMouseOver" Value = "True">
                    <Setter Property = "Foreground" Value = "{Binding BackgroundColor, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

 <Grid>
        <Button Width = "100" Height = "70" Style = "{StaticResource TriggerStyle}" Content = "Trigger"/>
</Grid>
```

Inthe view model I set the background color to green.
In the viewModel I have:

```
private void GetBackgroundColor()
{
   return _brush = Brushes.Green;
}
public Brush BackgroundColor
{
    get
    {
       return _brush;
    }
    set
    {
       _brush = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("BackgroundColor");
    }
}
```

In the debug mode, the brush has the value, but on screen nothing happens.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have a typo: `OnPropertyChanged("BackColor")` - property is called Back**ground**Color.

Comment: And that still won't work. Unless he's on win xp

Comment: From win 7 onwards. The button template has a rectangle in it which gives the default light blue background when you mouse over. In order to change the button background you need to change the template. Please see the link above.

Comment: And.  Please google before asking questions.... or posting answers.